# Flex - Show/Hide ComboBox based off selection

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Is it possible to show or hide a comboBox based off the selection made in another comboBox. I have been looking for documentation on this to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in a Change handler of ComboBox1 set ComboBox2's visible property to false based on the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Along with setting the combobox's visible property, if you want the form to act as if the combobox is not there, also set the includeInLayout property.